# NotePad++ - How to make changes to highlighted differences in Compare?

Tags: text, notepad++, text-editor, text-comparison

I am comparing two texts using Notepad++'s Compare plugin. For convenience, I would like the ability to make a small change to every highlighted difference. I would like it to make every word uppercase, but it could be something as simple as adding an asterix (Because then I could use Regex to make it uppercase). So basically:

```
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. | The nimble brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

to

```
    The QUICK brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. | The NIMBLE brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

or even just

```
    The *quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. | The *nimble brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

It appears as though there is nothing I can do with the highlighted differences. It is merely for viewing. Searching this on Google has brought up "Marking", but i can't figure out how that can help and I still can't Mark every change. This is becoming rather mind boggling. Searching seems to only bring about generic descriptions of the compare plugin or the Marking feature. Is there a way I can do this? Thank you, in advance.